# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'xxxxxx to data type int

Tags: sql-server, substring, type-conversion, varchar, charindex

I am trying to extract a string from a column - where the position of the string may vary; but it always starts with `userid=` and finishes with `=|`

I have almost got it working, but I keep getting the error

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'userid=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=' to data type int

My silly question lies around where should I add the convert command?

My query looks like this:

```
select 
    left(substring ([Column 1],
    charindex('userid=', [Column 1]) +7, 48),
    charindex('=|', [Column 1] - 1))
from 
    [mytable]
```

Comment: Its mySql I assume, since you have not tagged

Comment: @ChetanVasudevan `charindex()` is a SQL Server function.

Comment: You have a `-1` misplaced, it should be `charindex('=|',[Column 1]) -1`.

Comment: thanks @AlbertoMartinez, - but now I get the error "
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function. The statement has been terminated"...

Comment: `left()` doesn't admit negative values, `charindex()` returns 0 if the string is not found, and you are subtracting always -1 without taking this into account.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
SELECT REPLACE(
LEFT(
    substring ([Column 1],
              charindex('userid=',[Column 1]) +7, 48),
              charindex('=|',[Column 1] )
)
  , '=|','')
FROM [mytable]
```